# How can I use selenium to drop in a specific place?

Tags: xpath, selenium, fullcalendar

I am trying to write a selenium test for a drag and drop operation.

I am dropping in a tr but I need to specify whereabouts on the row as the tr itself covers 5 slots (this is for a calendar app) but the slots are not td's so I think the app might be using some sort of x,y co-ordinates within the tr.

Specifically the tr that goes all the way across is

```
<tr class="fc-slot15 fc-minor">
  <th class="fc-agenda-axis fc-widget-header"></th>
  <td class="fc-widget-content">
    <div style="position:relative"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

So far the best xpath I have is `xpath=(//table//tr[contains(@class,'fc-slot15')]//td)` but this identifies the whole tr.

Visually it looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to do it for full-calendar but how to drop in a specified place seems general enough.

Could I do it with mouse down, mouse move(x,y), mouse up perhaps?

Comment: Can't help you with selenium, but your XPath expression should select *all `<td/>` inside the given `<tr/>`s*. Did you cut down the full `<tr/>` node before pasting it here?